# Website without SSL was showing unwanted ads, after adding SSL they are gone. What caused the unwanted content appear?

Tags: security, ssl, code-injection

I have a website that was unmantained for a while and my client calls me to inform that the site is "showing obscene" ads between the site normal content. I checked, that the site didn ´t have SSL and a first security measure, added SSL certificate.

after the certificate was introduced, the "obscene banners" disappear from my client´s screen. I suspect that his computer had some kind of malware that injected content on the website. Is this correct? Whas not having SSL making the site vulnerable to content injection and the introduction of the certificate what prevented the infected machine to continue doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without HTTPS the content is vulnerable to sniffing **and modification** by some man in the middle. This might be some process on the local machine, on your router, at the router in a public WiFi hotspot or even your ISP. It is not unheard of ISP trying to get even more money from their users by injecting ads into the traffic.

HTTPS prevents both sniffing and modification of the payload and thus prevents such injections.